# How can I use my personal class with Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, class, import

I have AclManager class in *library/AclManager.php* and this code in *public/index.php*

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

Zend_Loader::loadClass("AclManager");
```

but the server throws an internal error (500). Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on manyxcxi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890672/how-can-i-use-my-personal-class-with-zend-framework/6890711#6890711) - here is how I would manage this:

- First, give your `AclManager` a "namespace". You can do this by renaming the class to `{Namespace}_AclManager` and moving it to `library/{Namespace}/AclManager.php`.
- Now it is as simple as registering your namespace with the Autoloader which you can do as manyxcxi pointed out **OR** you can simply add it to your `application.(ini|xml|etc)`.

Here is an example `application.xml`:

```
<autoloaderNamespaces>
    <{Namespace}>{Namespace}_</{Namespace}>
</autoloaderNamespaces>
```

... and here is the equivilant in `application.ini`:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "{Namespace}_"
```

Obviously, you'll want to replace `{Namespace}` in everything above with your own custom namespace - like `App` or maybe `Aegidius`.

Answer (score -1):

It's all about setting up your bootstrap for it to be auto loaded correctly.
This should be the first function of your bootstrap.php file:

```
// resources are bootstrapped in order, so be sure dependencies for
    // resources are listed first. you can explicitly bootstrap a resource by
    // calling $this->bootstrap('resource').

    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        // enable classic PEAR-like class autoloading
        $autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
        $autoloader->registerNamespace('Ashurex_');


    }
```

Replace Ashurex with your namespace, but make sure to keep the trailing _.
The set fallback auto loader will allow ZF to pick up classes in a more 'loose' pattern. You don't have to define a bunch of namespaces and such. There may be times when you don't want this set to true, but for just getting going it helps.

**-- EDIT --**

After you define your namespace, you will want to put your classes in your project/library/namespace folders. For instance, if I have a class named Ashurex_Testing_MyClass I would have it stored at project/library/Ashurex/Testing/MyClass.php. It's important to recognize that _ in a classname are like dots in Java. They're essentially directory/file paths.

Answer (score -3):

Remove the comma of:

```
 get_include_path(),
```

**Update: Apparently this could not solve the problem ;-)**

Comment: That has no bearing on the include path. He's simply pulling all the values into an array at that point.

Comment: @Jens Struwe: You are incorrect, using comma after the last entry within array is best practice, as eg. adding another item in array will be visible by version control systems as change in one line, not in two of them.

Comment: Yes this was a quick idea I should have added as a comment to the question.